# What is the difference between JRE options java.awt.headless and java.awt.headlesslib?

Tags: java, awt

I have used the former many times (`-Djava.awt.headless=true`) in order to prevent the infamous "no DISPLAY found" error for some applications which used some graphics methods in the JRE.

But since then I have also learned of the existence of the second one. In spite of hours of searching around, I cannot find a difference between both.

And to make matters worse, I am no GUI expert at all... So, is there an actual difference? What code would work with one and not the other, or would require both etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.awt.headlesslib` is part of a **temporary workaround** added in 2001 in response of bug [JDK-4407772](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4407772).

If you download the source code of [openjdk6](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/), [openjdk7](http://www.java.net/download/openjdk/jdk7/promoted/b147/openjdk-7-fcs-src-b147-27_jun_2011.zip) or [openjdk8](http://www.java.net/download/openjdk/jdk8/promoted/b132/openjdk-8-src-b132-03_mar_2014.zip) and grep all the source files looking for `java.awt.headlesslib` you will see no results.

So the effect of setting `java.awt.headlesslib` is null and the effect of setting `java.awt.headless` is to activate the headless mode.

Comment: That is some digging... I couldn't manage to get that far down! That's +500 for you, when I can award the bounty, that is... Thanks for the links and research!

Comment: To my eyes, you deserve it fully, no need to thank me ;) But I appreciate the thought, though :p